# Getting historic daily spend from Facebook Marketing API v2.5

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I've inherited a PHP application that accesses v2.3 of the Facebook Marketing API to get daily spend (and other info) per ad.  I'm upgrading it to v2.5. I'd like to be able to specify a date and get the insights for that ad for that date.  I've tried specifying date_range with a time_increment of 1, but I get only one result set back which seems to contain the totals to date, even if I use a 'since' and 'until' of a single historic date.

```
    function getAds($campaign_id, $time_start, $time_end){
  $params = array(
    'fields'=>array('id', 'effective_status', 'name'),
    'include_deleted'=>true,
    'time_increment'=>1,
    'time_range'=>array("since"=>$time_start,"until"=>$time_end));
  $resp = $this->api->call("/{$campaign_id}/ads/",FacebookAds\Http\RequestInterface::METHOD_GET,$params);
  return $resp->getContent();
}
```

Any pointers as to what I may be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I was accessing the wrong edge!  I needed to access "/{$ad_id}/insights/" with the time_range and time_increment fields.  The data is then returned in a array grouped by 1 day increments.